# Getting false from json_encode after upgrading from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5

Tags: php, json

This morning i hit a strange problem. All my json ReST like web services on my dev environment where down and nothing worked after upgrading the server from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5.

All i could find was that json_encode returned false when encoding my results to the output buffer. Nothing else changed, the rest was intact...

Read on to find the anwser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i had to use a tweak in the past to encode on the fly information that i used

```
if(json_encode($value) == 'null' && mb_detect_encoding($value) != 'UTF-8)
```

did not respond correctly anymore!

In fact, json_encode was now returning (bool)false instead of (string)'null' when the encoding failed.